positive eigenfunctions of elliptic PDE
I was wondering the following: Suppose one has a divergence free vector field $u$, and is interested in solutions to the elliptic PDE
$$
 \lambda f+u \cdot \nabla f=\Delta f
$$
where $Re(\lambda)>0$. Is it necessarily the case that $f=0$?
Of course, if one can integrate by parts, this is trivially true, since then because of the divergence free condition, it holds
$$
\lambda \|f\|_{L^2} =-\|\nabla f\|_{L^2}
$$
I am therefore mainly interested in the case where $f$ is unbounded at infinity.
It is also worth noting that in the case where $u$ is zero, simply taking the Fourier transform would show that $\lambda \hat{f}=-|\xi|^2\hat{f}$, which shows that the only tempered distribution which satisfies this equation is $0$.
Does this hold in general for say any $u$ with at most polynomial growth at infinity? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!
